# Hitting 100 active connections limit in test env with only two users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda

I have a single web client and a few Lambda functions which use the Admin SDK. I've noticed recently that I've bumped into the 100 simultaneous connection limit but I really shouldn't be anywhere near that limit. Also it would appear that the connections established by my Lamba functions are not dropping off even after the function has completed.

Any idea on:

- how I can prevent this run-up on connections from happening?
- how I can release connections established by past Lambda scripts?
- how can I monitor which processes/threads/stacks are holding connections?

> Note: this is a testing environment I'm working out of so I'd prefer to keep this in the free tier and my requirements should definitely not be running into the 100 active limit. I am on a paid plan in prod.

---

I attempt to avoid calling `initializeApp` more than once by using the following connection code. In the example I'm talking about I only have a single database as a backend and so the default "name" of **DEFAULT** is used each time.

```
const runningApps = new Set(firebase.apps.map(i => i.name));
this.app = runningApps.has(name)
  ? firebase.app()
  : firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: config.databaseUrl
    });
```

---

I'm now trying to explicitly close connections with `goOffline` but that leads to another issue where on the second connection -- aka, where the DEFAULT application is already setup and it just *reuses* the connection already established I get the following logging:

```
# Generated as result of `goOnline`
Connecting to Firebase: [https://xyz.firebaseio.com]
appears to be already connected
# Listening on ".info/connected" comes back as true, resulting in:
AbstractedAdmin: connected to [DEFAULT]
# but then I get this error
NotAllowed: You must first connect before using the database() API at Object._getFirebaseType
```

Comment: How did you determine how many instances Amazon spun up for your lambda function? Do you know if it spun down (and correctly disconnected) other instances?

Comment: How can I tell if it correctly disconnected? As for the functions spinning down, I can see from the logs that the function in question has timed out at 10 seconds. This should result in a normal spin down.

Comment: The fact that you have unexpected incoming connections to the database, makes it seem like the stale instances keep an open connection. Best I can think off is to call `goOffline()` in your function before it completes to explicitly disconnect.

Comment: Yeah I was considering that but the docs made it sound like this wasn't explicitly the use-case for explicitly disconnecting

Comment: If Lambda leaves the instances with lingering connections, it might be the best option. Give it a shot, and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I am attempted your suggestion @FrankvanPuffelen but while my simple CLI example worked, I'm now getting problems as described above. Do you know if `goOnline` is asynchronous? Docs suggest it is not.

Comment: Both `goOnline` and `goOffline` are synchronous calls afaik. But there's definitely going to be some time between going online and the data becoming available in your app.

Comment: Ok the explicit calls to `goOffline` are indeed working. @FrankvanPuffelen do you want to write an "answer" and I'll mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have unexpected incoming connections to the database, makes it seem like the stale instances keep an open connection.

Best I can think off is to call `goOffline()` in your function before it completes to explicitly disconnect. That would probably also mean you have to call `goOnline` at the start of the function, since it might be running on an instance that previously went offline. Both `goOnline` and `goOffline` are synchronous calls afaik, but there's definitely going to be some time between going online and the data becoming available in your app.

If Lambda has a way for you to detect life-cycle events of its instances, that would be the preferred place to call `goOffline` and `goOnline`.

Answer (score 0):

`admin.initializeApp` should only get called once in your script/node app.

The Firebase SDK's talks HTTP2 to the Firebase cloud system, so I'm not sure why you would encounter max connection issues as unique sockets are not stood up per call.

One thing to look out for is that calls to 3rd part API's (such as sendgrid) are not supported on the free tier.

Comment: Is it HTTP2? Pretty sure it's a websocket. No matter though, your point is still valid and I certainly would not want to call `initializeApp` more than once and my connection code tests for a similarly named app instance. I've added the code for this above.

Comment: Also, WRT to 3rd party API's ... this seems like it would be fully separate. Is there some integration built between Firebase and SendGrid? I am using SendGrid but that's working fine.